# Обновить таблицу если изменилась коллекция

Tags: java

Здравствуйте. Суть такова.

Есть база данных, которая содержит несколько колонок. Есть jFrame, в котором через jTableModel реализован вывод БД в таблице на экран. Посредником между БД и jTableModel стоит коллекция, которая заполняется значениями при подключении к БД. Также в jFrame есть форма добавления новых значений в БД(несколько текстовых полей для заполнения + кнопка записать), которая работает. Программа реализована так, что при добавлении через форму нового значения, оно сразу же сохраняется в БД через SQL запрос, и затем сразу же происходит добавление в коллекцию. Я хочу, чтоб эти изменения также прошли динамически с таблицей в jFrame. В таком случае я скорее всего должен использовать TableModelListener. Но в каком случае он заработает? Может я должен еще + ко всему этому как то переподать по новой коллекцию в таблицу, как здесь `TableModel model = new Table(all)` ???

```
static ArrayList<MyBeans> all = new ArrayList<MyBeans>();// коллекция

TableModel model = new Table(all);
JTable table = new JTable(model);//таблица

//Динамичиское изменение
table.getModel().addTableModelListener(new TableModelListener(){
@Override
 public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent e) {
   System.out.println("zzz");//Какое нибудь событие на запуска обработчика
 }
});
```

Я уверен, что представить это без кода не легко, но код громоздкой, думаю нет надобности его вставлять. Если требуются, могу внести дополнительные разъяснения. Спасибо заранее.

Answer (score 1):

Привет.
Вот тут написано https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/tablemodellistener.html
что TableModel по умолчанию управляет строками. Для того, чтобы тебе задать свое поведение, тебе надо сделать свою TableModel, заимплиментирова интерфейс TableModel.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#data
Вот тут есть пример (вроде как).

А еще возможнен 2 вариант - ты делаешь свою коллекцию, которая наследуется от ArrayList, там в конструктор добавляешь свой листенер, и в реализации метода add ты вызываешь это листенер. Приведу пример кода

```
public class MyArrayList extends ArrayList<MyBeans> {
   private MyListener myListener;

   public MyArrayList(MyListener mL) {
      this.myListener = mL;
   }

   @Override
   public boolean add(MyBeans mB) {
       boolean res = super.add(s);
       myListener.update(mb);
   }
   ...
}

public interface MyListener {
   void update(MyBeans mb);
}
```

Твой класс

```
 final TableModel model = new Table(all);
 JTable table = new JTable(model);//таблица
 MyArrayList<MyBeans> all = new MyArrayList<MyBeans>(new MyListener()      {
    public void update(MyBeans mb) {
       model.addRow(mb); //как-то так
    }
 });
```